# Cannot echo out the right result. PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a code that check if a value in an exact column is equal to an 'neodobren', and if there is such value in the column to echo out the button 'Add Member' and Yes for each value. I've tried to do the following and it is not echoing the Yes:
I have the following MySQL table content:

```
UID Name    Phone   Email   SchoolGymnasium City    Password    Status  
1                                                               neodobren
2                                                               neodobren
```

and I have the following PHP code inside the HTML index page:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","****","****");
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("***", $con);
include("../../sql.php");
session_start();
$zaqvki = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Directors WHERE Status='neodobren' LIMIT 1");
            if(mysql_num_rows($zaqvki) > 0) {
echo '<div align="right"><a href="add/director/" class="btn add-project">Add Member</a></div><br>';

        // display data in table


        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($zaqvki)) {  //$zaqvki was $result, before a guy comment me this...

                echo "Yes"; 
        } }
         else { 
                echo "No";
                }
```

It is showing only the button add member, and not showing the Yes, which must be echo-ed.

Comment: you're using $result instead of $zaqvki

Comment: I've replaced it but is still not showing the Yes'es

Comment: if you turn on error_reporting, right above your while loop, do you get anything? with
`error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: debug by above mentioned error reporting, look what variable has what contents etc. Then format your code so it's not all over the place (please try and use usefull indentation). Finally, steer away fropm the mysql_* functions. did you see the manual? did you see the BIG RED warning?

Comment: Using a loop on a database result that can have at most one row (since you are using `LIMIT 1`) does not make much sense.

Comment: I have removed LIMIT 1; and it is still not adding them

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc to get an associative array and make a comparison on each row of a certain column:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    if($row['Status'] === 'neodobren')
        echo "Yes";
    else
        echo "No";
}
```